# How can I fix Y at 2 if my X is more than 2000?

Tags: javascript, linear-equation

I have this line of equation in my JavaScript code.

```
Y= M*X + C
Y= -0.001*(X) + 4.1
```

My value for `Y` should be `2` at maximum, meaning my `X` input should be `2000` at max. However, I could not set the limit of `X` to `2000` as I would need the actual value of `X` for later calculation.

How can I fix `Y` at `2` if my `X` is more than `2000`?

This is my code in javascript

```
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = (-0.001*(x) + 4.1);
```

Comment: If your `Y` needs to be at most `2`, use `Y = Math.min(2, -0.001 * X + 4.1);`, or `Y = -0.001 * Math.min(2000, X) + 4.1`, if `X` needs to be at most `2000`, or the option with the ternary expression below.

Comment: `Y = (X > 2000) ? 2 : M*X+C;`

Comment: The coefficient of X is negative so values of X greater than 2000 are not the problem, values of X less than 2100 are: `-0.001*2100+4.1=2`. The correct solution is `Math.min(-0.001*X+4.1,2)`

Comment: @Xufox i dont understand what you guys mean, i have updated my question showing how i display the result pls check. Thanks

Comment: @jsheeran  i dont understand what you guys mean, i have updated my question showing how i display the result pls check. Thanks

Comment: @Nick  i dont understand what you guys mean, i have updated my question showing how i display the result pls check. Thanks

Comment: @Nick i have tried and it is worked but this is not what im looking for, if my X is lesser than 2000 it will just display the value 2

Comment: What I was saying is that for the formula you have given, Y will be greater than 2 if X is less than 2100 (not > 2000, as you stated in your question). What @Xufox and I were both saying is that to make sure Y is never greater than 2, you should use `Math.min` which will ensure the value of Y is equal to the formula if the result is <2, or 2 otherwise.

Comment: @Nick ok thanks i have used your method and it work!! Thanks alot!!!

Comment: Great to hear. Thank @Xufox too as he commented it first.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for your help bro!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var Y = Math.max((-0.001*(Length * Width) + 4.1),4);
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Y= M*X + C
Y= -0.001*(X) + 4.1
```

You can add condition after Y calculation and change value of Y.

```
Y = Y > 2 ? 2 : Y
```

Or you can add condition directly on X

```
Y = X > 2000 ? 2 : (M*X + C)
```

so according to your value

```
Y = X > 2000 ? 2 : (-0.001*(x) + 4.1)

document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = Y;
```

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, i have updated my question showing how i display the result pls check. Thanks